# Getting a 403 Forbidden message when trying to upload files to Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am getting the following error when trying to upload files to the Azure blob storage. This was working fine before. Does anyone know why it would return a 403 Forbidden message? I am using C# in ASP.NET MVC and have installed the client library for Windows Azure Storage.

> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1322
>      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +1144
>
> [StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.]
>      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync(RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) +4529
>      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamHelper(Stream source, Nullable`1 length, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) +1303
>      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(Stream source, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) +29
>      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(String path, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) +84

Comment: [Possible answer](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/are-you-getting-a-403-forbidden-from-windows-azure-storage-services/), [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630150/azure-blob-storage-upload-error-403-forbidden), [Possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803651/403-error-when-testing-azure-blob-storage-upload), [Possible answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0526ccc4-63e3-404f-a355-28179b6e88cb/getting-403-forbidden-webexception-azure-blob-put-request?forum=windowsazuredata)

Comment: @Spectarion Thanks but I've seen most of those link. In my case it was totally a different issue. I had to disable Application Insights to make that work. Clarifying with Microsoft engineers at the moment.

Comment: Please, for the future readers, answer your own question and mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the 403 exception, it seems that you have no access to the container.

> This was working fine before

If you are using Azure storage account key to access the resource, please have a try to make sure that account key is not changed or you could regenerate it and try it again.

If you are using Service [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1), please have a try to make sure that it is not out of date. You also could use Azure portal or [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to regenerate SAS token and try it again.

**Update:**

According to the comment:

Azure storage also support [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services), more detail please refer to document. We also could set CORS from azure portal, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am not using SAS. I have also tried a new key. Is it possible for Azure to forbid the requests from just a specific domain? If so is there anywhere I can allow access in the portal? I can upload files to the same container from another domain.

Comment: Azure storage also support CORS, more detail please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services). We also could set CORS from azure portal. I  will update the answer with screenshot.

Comment: I have been looking into CORS but was wondering why I will have to set that if the container works from the another domain. It works if I point the staging domain to this container. It also works from my local. The only difference is that the live domain where it is not working uses https and app insights is enabled.

Comment: I will try setting up CORS and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Setting up CORS hasn't made any difference

Comment: Would you mind sharing you connection string format?  We could get the connectionstring from azure portal `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountName;AccountKey=xxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

Comment: I had already checked the connection string. Endpoint Suffix wasn't there in my previous connection string. It didn't work with or without it anyway. Good news is that, I have fixed it! It was the Application Insights. I had to hide the Instrumentation Key in the ApplicationInsights.config  and remove the lines in web.config to go with it. Not sure if this is a bug in Application Insights but I will have to enable this back soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the problem was the Networking blade of the Storage Account. I needed to (temporarily) configure the Firewall by adding the IP of my development machine.